# how to sort names with numbers using mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I'm using mongoose, wants to sort name but it goes wrong

the names here is like :
A1,A2,A3,A11,A12,A13,B1,B2,B3,B10,B11

my line is

```
this.find(condition).collation({ locale: "en"}).sort({name: 1}).skip(offset).limit(limit)
```

what I expect:

```
A1,A2,A3,A11,A12,A13,B1,B2,B3,B10,B11
```

what I got:

```
A1,A11,A12,A13,A2,A3,B1,B10,B11,B2,B3
```

so the question is very clear...How should I do to make it right, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it looks like it is sorting by strings, and with strings, only the first digit counts, then the second. This obviously isn't what you want. The only way you can sort by numbers is by sorting it manually with Vanilla JS.

Comment: I'm not sure how, can you explain more ?

Comment: So basically, you remove the sort part from your mongoose query, which will give you an array of documents you can perform operations on. You can then do anything with Vanilla JS

Comment: the last part of query is for pagination, use data the query returned to sort will got wrong sort...